# How can we create a Azure Pipeline(yaml approach) using Azure Devops rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How can we create a Azure Pipeline(yaml approach) using Azure Devops rest apis.
Basically I am trying to create a new pipeline programmatically and not through Azure Devops portal
I referred to this link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
but this does not provide the exact json body format required to create and configure a new pipline pointing to code repo. Kindly help me here

Comment: Create your pipeline with the web interface and use the GET from API to see the JSON format : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 2):

You can first use the [Pipelines - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to check the definition json of the pipeline, and change the fields accordingly.

You can define the request body json as below, when calling `Pipelines - Create` rest api:

```
$body = @{
  configuration=@{
                    variables=@{
                                customVariable=@{
                                        value="value"
                                }
                    };
                    path="azure-pipelines.yml";
                    repository=@{
                                    id=  "repository-id";
                                    name="repository-name"
                                    type=  "azureReposGit"
                                  };
                    type=  "yaml"
       };
   name=  "pipeline-name";
   folder= "\\"
 }
```

The `variables` field define the pipeline Variables in the UI Page:

[image]

The `path` field points to pipeline yaml file in the code repo.

The `repository` field defines the code repo this pipeline targets to.

The `folder` field defines which folder the pipeline is placed:

[image]

---

If you use [Build Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to create the yaml pipeline. You can check below request body json example:

```
$body='{ "variables":  {
                      
                      "customVariable":  {
                                 "value":  "customValue",
                                 "allowOverride":  true
                             }
                  },
 
    "process":  {
                    "yamlFilename":  "azure-pipelines.yml",
                    "type":  2
                },
    "repository":  {
                       "id":  "repo-id",
                       "type":  "TfsGit",
                       "name":  "repo-Nanme",
                       
                       "defaultBranch":  "refs/heads/master",
                       "clean":  null,
                       "checkoutSubmodules":  false
                   },
  
    "name":  "pipeline-name",
  
    "path":  "\\",
    "type":  "build",
    "queueStatus":  "enabled",
    
    "project":  {
                    "id":  "project-id",
                    "name":  "project-name"
                   
                }
}'
```

Update:

If you code repo is Githbub. You will have to create a [github service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-github) in your azure devops project. And then pass the connection id in your api resquest body.

```
$body = @{
      configuration=@{
                        variables=@{
                                    customVariable=@{
                                            value="value"
                                    }
                        };
                        path="azure-pipelines.yml";
                        repository=@{
                                    
                                    FullName="githubAccount/repoName";
                                    type=  "gitHub";
                                    Connection= @{
                                                   id=  "github service connection id"
                                                  }
                                  };
                        type=  "yaml"
           };
       name=  "pipeline-name";
       folder= "\\"
     }
```

You can get the service connection id in the address bar. See below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response @Levi.I initially got this error:"message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: Url". But then I passed the value for URL under repository and it created a new pipeline. But now am unable to edit or open the settings from Azure Devops UI and it displays the following error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: serviceEndpointId" Also how can execute the pipeline immediatley after it is created programatically

Comment: Is your code repository on github? Are there any service connections having been used in the pipeline?

Comment: Yes my code repo is GitHub.yes I have used service connection name in my pipeline @Levi

Comment: If you code repo is Githbub. You will have to create a [github service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-github) in your azure devops project. And then pass the connection id in your api resquest body. See above update.